# react native how can I use two items side by side in modal?

Tags: react-native, expo

how can I use two items side by side in modal ?

Normally I make it like this:

```
flex-direction: 'row'
```

but in modal with flatlist, how I make it ? look at the bottom the picture. I want 2 names side by side.

Code:

```
import React, { useRef, forwardRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';
import faker from 'faker';
import { useCombinedRefs } from '../../utils/use-combined-refs';

export const SnappingList = forwardRef((_, ref) => {
  const modalizeRef = useRef(null);
  const contentRef = useRef(null);
  const combinedRef = useCombinedRefs(ref, modalizeRef);

  const getData = () =>
    Array(10)
    .fill(0)
    .map(_ => ({
      name: faker.name.findName(),
      email: faker.internet.email(),
      image: faker.image.avatar()
    }));

  const profile_image = faker.image.avatar();

  const getHeader = () => {
    return (
    <View style={s.modalContainer}>
      <Text>I AM A HEADER</Text>
    </View>)
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity style={s.item}>
      <Text style={s.item__name}>{item.name}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  return (
    <Modalize
      ref={combinedRef}
      contentRef={contentRef}
      snapPoint={350}
      flatListProps={{
        data: getData(),
        renderItem: renderItem,
        ListHeaderComponent: getHeader(),
        keyExtractor: item => item.email,
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false,
        removeClippedSubviews: true,
        initialNumToRender: 5
      }}
    />
  );
});
```

[image]

..............................

Comment: I solved with: numColumns: 2, but thanks for reply!

Comment: Please do not add solutions as an edit. They belong in the answer space. If you think the solution will not be helpful to anyone else, you can delete the question, but if a solution might help someone else, please add an answer

Comment: Put the solution in the right place or add solved in title. So others will not waste time by clicking the question to answer it.